# Why isn't this C# Regex working?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string (from a large HTML string):

```
href="/cgi-bin/pin.cgi?pin=94841&sid=9548.1386389012.v1"><
```

And here is my code:

```
var sids = Regex.Matches( htmlCode, "sid=(.)\">" );
```

I'm not pulling back any results. Is my Regex correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is what it should be:

```
var str = @"href=""/cgi-bin/pin.cgi?pin=94841&sid=9548.1386389012.v1"">";
var sid = Regex.Match(str, @"sid=([^""]*)");
Console.WriteLine (sid.Groups[1].Value);
```

What you originally posted was wrong because "." acts as a wildcard, and the way you presented it meant that it would only capture 1 character, the problem with wildcards is that they're difficult to stop till you reach the end of a line, so never use them unless you have to.

Answer (score 0):

`.` match only single character. To match multiple character you should use `*` or `+` modifier: `(.+)`; or more preferably non-greedy version: `(.+?)`

Use `@"verbatim string literal"` if possible for regular expression.

```
var sids = Regex.Matches(htmlCode, @"sid=(.+?)""");
```

See [demo run](http://ideone.com/yZ0HQo).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty close. Consider the following minor change to your regex...

```
sid=.*?\">
```

Good Luck!